# How to save JSONArray in dynamically created collection in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I'm passing this as a array,

```
{ "formData": [
    {"Temp":"123",
    "Oil":"456"}
  ], 
  "formId": 2
}
```

```
class FormDataRequest {
private Long formId;
private JSONArray formData;

//with getters and setters
```

I want to insert this data in collection which I have **dynamically** created in mongoDB,

This is my code -

```
BasicDBObject dbo = new BasicDBObject();
dbo.put(formFieldLists.getName(), formDataRequest.getFormData().get(0));

collection.insert(dbo);
```

I am not able to save values in the collections.

Please help me with the code.

Comment: Are there any errors emitted, if yes what are they?

Comment: Please post the problem you are facing when inserting the document, any error messages?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any error. But I'm not able to store values in the collcetion.  Only ObjectId is getting generated for every hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by doing this,

```
  BasicDBObject dbObject = null;

    JSONArray data = (JSONArray) formDataRequest.getFormData();

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {

    dbObject = new BasicDBObject();

    Map<String, String> jsonoobjarr = (LinkedHashMap<String, String>) data.get(i);

        if (jsonoobjarr != null) {

        System.out.println(jsonoobjarr);

        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

        String s = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(timestamp);


        dbObject.put("created_at", s);
        dbObject.put("updated_at", null);

        dbObject.putAll(jsonoobjarr);

        }
       collection.insert(dbObject);

      }
```

And this is working properly for me. Just posted the solution if someone need this in future.